# Do questions referencing blogs generate trackbacks?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is a test to see if a trackback is created for [a posting at my blog](http://ambergis.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/rfidgeospatial-relief-for-haiti/) if I reference it in SE.

Update:  OK, it doesn't look like this happens, so I'm changing this to a feature request.

There are a lot of bloggers out there who would likely prefer to answer questions pertaining to their blog at SE rather than in the comments section of their blog.  Trackbacks would encourage this.

**Update**: After reading about [plans to shut down Gadgets Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/) I thought I would elaborate on how this feature could generate more traffic.  A lot of bloggers post articles about technical subjects.  Readers then post questions in the comments section of the post.  Many of these questions could be answered by someone other than the blog author.  If questions in stack exchange generated trackbacks, I think a lot of bloggers would join.  Since many bloggers are [mavens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maven), they would, in turn, attract even more users to stackexchange.