# GIS StackExchange Blog - Launch

Tags: discussion, blog

**GIS Stack Exchange Blog - Launch**

http://gis.blogoverflow.com/

**Looking for more Authors and Blog Posts**
Submit your requests in the comments
If you want to do your own post please notify mapperz or underdark who can give you access (wordpress invite).

Thanks to the positive feedback so far - if you want more ask.

update Twitter Feed on the blog points to our own GIS Question (auto tweet) so seamlessly links back to the main site.
http://gis.blogoverflow.com/ [right side panel]
(thanks to Rebecca once again).

3rd Post this week - continuing the good start
http://gis.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/maperitive-tutorial-generating-osm-map-for-adobe-illustrator-in-seven-easy-steps/
(Thanks to [Igor Brejc](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/users/198/igor-brejc))

2nd Post (13th September 2011) is General GIS SE FAQ - hopefully a useful reminder to new and existing users how GISse is to work.
http://gis.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/a-quick-guide-to-gis-stack-exchange-questions/

Another Author has already added another post - likley to be published tomorrow.

So the ball is rolling now - hopefully other members will want to start add topics and details for their own post - can be solo or joint effort.

Based on Wordpress so it can be customized to our needs.

**Content is King**

New content will be coming soon from community members from the GIS Stack Exchange.

2 Authors are wanting to post already - great news

Popular & reoccurring topics on GIS.SE, events related to GIS and the GIS.SE community with a random collection of posts by different authors will give a good wide cross-section of articles.

```
Popular questions will be also expanded.
Commercial and Open Source related GIS posts (includes beta software) are welcomed.
Community GIS News and Events will also be included
```

**More importantly - What is missing?**

Ideas - Polling/Voting

Want to be an author? add your support to the comments

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-polls/
is this a good tool/idea?

Resources:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page

Comment: Perhaps you can give some info on how to post, suggest a topic/...

Comment: @johanvdw thanks for your interest - have sent you an invite as author. Topics can be requested here in the comments

Comment: Word Press Roles - http://en.support.wordpress.com/user-roles/

Comment: I've changed the blog link on the main site to point to the per-site blog and hooked up the twitter account to tweet new blog entries.

Comment: Thanks for doing that Rebecca

Comment: FYI we have deployed a new design for GIS blog to match the main site. No more Sketchy!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how many visitors the blog has received, but it is very hard to find through the site. Since the initial banner on the front page in the first week of release, the only link on the site seems to be in a tiny font all the way at the bottom of the page.

[image: well hidden..]

On meta there is a blog link in the same location with a "new" sign, but this points to http://blog.stackexchange.com/

[image]

Comment: I agree this is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

When leaving a comment I found the captcha image a bit too cryptic ... can we adjust the crypticity?

Also, I wonder if the SE staff could integrate wordpress identity to automatically recognize gis.SE users who've already logged in and automatically use their identities for comments without requiring any captcha test.

I think we want (good) questions about topics in the blog to appear in the main Q&A site instead of as comments under a blog.  However, when I asked [a question that references the blog](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14661/do-questions-referencing-the-blog-create-trackbacks), I don't see any sort of trackback at the bottom of the blog.

See also [my related feature request.](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145/do-questions-referencing-blogs-generate-trackbacks)

Comment: Tying blog identity to SE is something people have asked for, it pretty much boils down to I just don't know how and haven't been able to sit down and figure it out yet. (:

Answer (score 1):

GIS SE Blog - unique visits:

```
week1 577
week2 190
week3 150
week4 80
this week so far 55
```

the drop is likely to be due to lack of posts so far (there is one pending - Kirk when is happy will post it).

On meta there is a blog link in the same location with a "new" sign, but this points to http://blog.stackexchange.com/
**correct - we don't have access to change this to the GIS Blog.**

Comment: So is there any chance of getting a link at the top of the main GIS SE page? It just seems to have no visibility - which is a shame.

Comment: the link 'blog' at the bottom of each page does link to the GIS blog. As said Moderators do not have access to change the blog at the top - It can be requested to Stack Exchange Staff to change the link to our own not the stack exchange blog.